# Redux form: REGISTER_FIELD / UNREGISTER_FIELD get called after change or focus events

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, immutable.js, redux-form

I’m using Redux Form to render and handle form events in my React app. The following things are used:

- Initial values
- Field arrays
- Immutable.js
- Material UI

Also, the field arrays are build using the initial values.

```
export default connect(
  state => {
    return {
      buttonVisible,
      confirm,
      initialValues: Immutable.Map({
        configuration_items: configuration_items,
      })
    }
  }
)(AssetConfiguration)
```

The problem is that *all* the fields in the form get deregistered and registered on *every* `change` or `focus` event. Without the `defaultValues`, it seems to work fine though.

I’m using a React component to render the form, something like this

```
class ConfigurationForm extends React.Component {
  renderTableBody({ fields, meta: { touched, error } }) {
    return(
      <tbody>
        {fields.map((field, index) => {
          return(
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>
                <Field fieldIndex={index} name={`${field}.value`} id={`${field}.value`} component={this.renderItemField.bind(this)} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    )
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <form className="defaultForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(postAssetConfiguration)}>
        <FieldArray name="configuration_items" component={this.renderTableBody.bind(this)} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

What could be the problem here?

Thanks,
Rens

Comment: I had a similar problem where I called const myFunc = message => value =>
  isEmpty(value) ? message : undefined; in the component body: myFunc(myMessage);. Moving the function call outside of the component made the register/unregister of the field stop.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still having issues, I had similar problem with `FieldArray` and my solution was to remove `bind` completely and put it in it's own component so that it doesn't re-render array. It has to be outside of the component that's rendering it  -

```
const renderItemField = ({ input }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input {...input} />
    </div>
  );
};

const renderTableBody = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error } }) => {
  return(
    <tbody>
      {fields.map((field, index) => {
        return(
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>
              <Field fieldIndex={index} name={`${field}.value`} id={`${field}.value`} component={renderItemField} />
            </td>
          </tr>
        )
      })}
    </tbody>
  )
};

class ConfigurationForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="defaultForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(postAssetConfiguration)}>
        <FieldArray name="configuration_items" component={renderTableBody} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm investigating a similar issue.
My guess is: you are passing in `this.renderTableBody.bind(this)` and `this.renderItemField.bind(this)` as components. Every time render is called, these will be new references, triggering an unnecessary rerender. This is considered bad practice: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md