# How can I insert a reduxForm component without starting too many calls

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using a MERN stack overall, but I think this question only applies to react and redux form.

Whenever I include a form to add an item within my user dashboard, I end up getting 

`Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

First, I am not calling componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate explicitly at all, so I am having trouble finding the issue. If I stop the development server, with say `CTRL+C` it sometimes renders the (now unusable) form for me.

I tried (all failed):

- to just include the form with no handlers
- to include the form and handle it on the dashboard
- to include the form and handle it on the form
- to remove all calls to `bind(this)` based on this [somewhat similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461770/redux-form-register-field-unregister-field-get-called-after-change-or-focus-e#45161379)

I have similar redux-forms (handled in their containers) that work fine for signup and signin

**UserDashboard.js** where the error happens when I add a form and works fine without it

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import * as actions from '../../actions';
import Cupcakes from './cupcakes';
import Monkeys from './monkeys';
import AddMonkeyForm from './add_monkey_form'


class UserDashboard extends Component {


    // handleSubmit({name}) {
    //     console.log("handleSubmitMonkey with", {name})
    //   //this.props.createMonkey({user, name})
    // }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="section">
                    <h1>Hi: {this.props.user.name}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="section">
                    <h2>Monkeys</h2>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col m6 s12">
                        <h4>Add a new monkey</h4>
                        <AddMonkeyForm /> // If I take this out, everything works, it fails whether or not I add a handle submit function
                        </div>
                        <div className="col m6 s12">Existing monkeys</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="section">
                    <h2>Cupcakes</h2>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col m6 s12">Add a new cupcake</div>
                        <div className="col m6 s12">Existing cupcakes</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const user = state.auth.user;
    const cupcakes = state.userdata.cupcakes;
    const monkeys = state.userdata.monkeys;
    return { user: user, monkeys: monkeys, cupcakes: cupcakes };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(UserDashboard);

// <AddMonkeyForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
```

**AddMonkeyForm.js** that causes the error - this one fails whether I try to call handlesubmit in AddMonkeyForm or in UserDashboard or not at all.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import renderTextField from '../helpers/form_helpers';
import { createMonkey } from '../../actions';

class AddMonkeyForm extends Component {
    onSubmit(values) {
        console.log('trying to submit MONKEY');
        // this.props.createMonkey(values, () =>{
        //     this.props.history.push('/');
        // });
    }
    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="section">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                    <Field
                        label="Name"
                        name="name"
                        placeholder="Fluffy"
                        component={renderTextField}
                        type="text"
                    />

                    <button
                        className="btn-large dark-primary-color"
                        type="submit"
                    >
                        Add Monkey
                        <i className="material-icons right">done</i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};

    if (!values.name) {
        errors.name = 'Please enter monkey name';
    }

    return errors;
};

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'addmonkey',
    validate
})(AddMonkeyForm);

//})(connect(null, { createMonkey })(AddMonkeyForm));
```

**The action in actions.js that I will eventually call with this**

```
export function createMonkey(userid, name) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        const url = `${USER_API_URL}/${userid}/monkey/new`;
        const request = axios.post(url, {
            headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}` },
            name
        });
        request
            .then(response => {
                console.log("createMonkey has RESPONSE", response.data.createdMonkey)
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_USER_MONKEYS,
                    payload: response.data.createdMonkey
                });
            })
            // If request is bad...
            // -Show an error to the user
            .catch(() => {
                console.log('error');
            });
    };
}
```

**usergetters.js reducer that will eventually update the userdata.monkeys state based on the form.

```
import { GET_USER_CUPCAKES, GET_USER_MONKEYS } from '../actions/types'

const initialUserData = [{cupcakes: [], monkeys: []}]

export default function userGetterReducer(state = initialUserData, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_USER_CUPCAKES:
      return {...state, cupcakes: action.payload}
    case GET_USER_MONKEYS:
      return {...state, monkeys: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

The project is on github. This particular error branch is `addmonkeyform1` if for some reason you end up on the master, it will look different than shown here. [Go to Project on Github](https://github.com/monkeywithacupcake/mern-cupcake/tree/addmonkeyform1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled the project down and am trying to find the source of the multiple calls. I am not sure where it is coming from. I'll update if I find anything further.

In the mean time you could do the following in App.js:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
  return nextState !== this.state;
}
```

This will prevent the re-rendering if the state has not changed.

Comment: Ok. I added that and the constant refresh stops. I made a new branch with that change called addmonkeyform2 that I am working from now. Thanks for the idea. I want to understand what caused the issue, but just stopping it gets me much closer to making the app work. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling handleSubmit(...) immediately, upon rendering the form.  I assume you want to call it only when the form is actually submitted, so you should change this line:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
```

to something like this:

```
<form onSubmit={(values) => methodYouWantToCallWhenTheFormIsSubmitted(values)}>
```